# Best and most efficient way to execute a Python script at Raspberry Pi (Raspbian Buster) every 5 seconds and store in PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, raspberry-pi, raspbian

How to do that the best way?

How to autostart and run the script every 5 seconds? (i read something from a rs232 device)
I want to write some values every 5 seconds to a postgresql database and for this is it ok to open the database connection every 5 seconds and close it or can it be stay opend?

thanks in advance

Comment: That's not a problem. What you should take into account is that this kind of constrant writing will break many SD cards rather quickly.

Comment: Is postgresql running on the Pi?

Comment: Yes it is running on the pi and on sd card! Will it be better to outsource the db file to a hdd drive?

Comment: @KlausD. that sounds a bit pessimistic!  [decent SD cards](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/27626/73541) will do wear leveling so you shouldn't need to worry about this too much.  just get a bigger card from a good brand and it should be able to tolerate a few segments/blocks failing

Comment: @sam-mason A pessimist is a realist with experience. My experience comes from writing IoT sensor data to databases on Raspberry Pis. The MTBF of SD cards was about 3 months with seperated partitions about 4. Used only top brand and class products, differences between manufacturers were minimal.

Comment: @KlausD. interesting! how were you defining "failed"? and what were the SD card sizes and IO rates?

Comment: @sam-mason Sorry, but that has to be enough for this side-discussion, it's not exactly on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to have a constantly running script that reads the value, sends to db, and sleeps for the remainer of the interval and keep the connection open. This way you can monitor and react if a read, write or both take too long for example. And then to have a separate script just to check if the main one is alive and notify you or restart the main one. I had some success with this model when reading from a bitcoin exchange api and inserting into mariadb every 6 seconds

Comment: note that `systemd` can [automatically restart services](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=) that fail.  just set `Restart=always`, see e.g. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md

Comment: True, but it's been always a pain for me to figure out the right stuff to write in those systemd unit files to get servicea run as I wanted